# eurodollar future options basics

Tags: options, option-pricing, futures

I am trying to understand how to calculate the P&L on a eurodollar futures options position. Suppose I am looking at say Dec-2023 99.125 strike put options with a bid-ask of 0.2250 - 0.415.

Since this is not a front month contract CME says that the minimum price fluctuation is one half of one basis point (0.005 = $12.50).

let's suppose the the eurodollar futures go to say 99, then would the profit on the Dec-2023 Eurodollar future options be calculated as ((99.125 - 99) - 0.415) X 100 = $-29.  (I'm assuming 1 contract).

So breakeven is: 99.125 - 0.415 = 98.71.

So would the premium (and therefore max risk) on this, assuming we buy at $0.415, be calculated as:

(0.415/0.005 = 83 ticks), 83 X 12.50 = $1,037.50.

One final thing, since this is an option on a future, is it marked-to-market like a future is, but just with maximum risk defined since we are buying a put?

Comment: Looks OK as far as I can see. Though I find it easier to say that 1 point on the future is worth 2500 USD, so a premium of 0.415 is 0.415*2500 = 1,037.50 USD. Same answer of course.

Comment: If the future goes to 99 the option is in the money by 99.125-99 = 0.125 points or 0.125*2500 = 312.50 USD. unfortunately you paid 1037.50 USD for the option so your P&L is 312.50-1037.50 = -725.00 USD. (This answer differs from yours. The 0.29 you found is in **points** not dollars which are worth 2500*0.29 = 725 USD).

Comment: The final thing: As with a future the exchange will publish a settlement price for the option at the end of the day (a single price, not a bid and an ask). Your statement the next morning will show figures for LOV and SOV (long option value and short option value). The value of your long put (at settlement price) will be included in LOV. The *Account Balance* in your futures account plus LOV minus SOV will be shown as your account's *Liquidation Value*. (Once you do a few trades you will find all this very simple. From your post you understand the basics well.).